# JSON properties not accessible

Tags: javascript, json

I have something like this:

```
var appointments = {

    "1" : [
        {"startTime" : "05:00:00", "endTime" : "07:00:00"},
        {"startTime" : "08:00:00", "endTime" : "09:00:00"}
    ],
    "2" : [
        {"startTime" : "07:00:00", "endTime" : "07:30:00"}   
    ],
    "3" : [
        {"startTime" : "09:00:00", "endTime" : "10:30:00"}
    ]

}
```

I want to separate the appointment properties. Now, if I try:

```
console.log(appointments[1]);
```

or

```
console.log(appointments['1']);
```

All I get is:

```
"
```

Something is terribly wrong here. I am not sure if my JSON is in correct format either. A complete newbie to JS. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try parsing it to JSON before doing the `console.log()` thing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w9r2th95/1/ - just fine

Comment: Its work fine.Show other code which using it

Comment: Actually this json is populated by using the `push` method. When I `console.log(appointments)` , I get the above written json. However, further actions applicable to a json are not working. Could there be something wrong with the method of how I am generating this json?

Comment: can you add a fiddle on how you are populating the JSON ? Your code works fine otherwise.